cartographer map to base_footprint tf variation issue in online mode
I'm working on an AGV. I have an Ouster os1 sensor. I want to use the cartographer online for 3d mapping for outdoor purposes. The robot base starts rotating and jumping in riz when I run the online mode. But everything works perfectly when using the bag file of the same agv and running it offline with the same lua configuration.
here's my Lua configuration:
include "map_builder.lua"
include "trajectory_builder.lua"
options = {
map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
map_frame = "map",
tracking_frame = "os_imu",
published_frame = "base_footprint",
odom_frame = "odom",
provide_odom_frame = false,
publish_frame_projected_to_2d = false,
use_pose_extrapolator = true,
use_odometry = false,
use_nav_sat = false,
use_landmarks = false,
num_laser_scans = 0,
num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,
num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 1,
num_point_clouds = 1,
lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,
submap_publish_period_sec = 0.5,
pose_publish_period_sec = 10e-3,
trajectory_publish_period_sec = 50e-3,
rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.0,
odometry_sampling_ratio = 1.0,
fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.0,
imu_sampling_ratio = 1.0,
landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.0,
}
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D.num_accumulated_range_data = 1
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D.voxel_filter_size = 0.1
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_3D.motion_filter = {
max_time_seconds = 0.5,
max_distance_meters = 0.05,
max_angle_radians = math.rad(1.0),
}
MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_3d = true
MAP_BUILDER.num_background_threads = 4
POSE_GRAPH.optimization_problem.huber_scale = 5e2
POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes = 320
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.sampling_ratio = 0.1
POSE_GRAPH.optimization_problem.ceres_solver_options.max_num_iterations = 10
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.min_score = 0.55
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.global_localization_min_score = 0.6
return options
I'm also sharing the video links of both offline and online modes.
Offline Mode:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGsanmPFC9AxBHR0N27yqAUkZSYr-JGc/view?usp=drive_link
Online Mode:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dgepW9d6bJvjeo7wgNVjWcZUMsp1QiFJ/view?usp=sharing
